# smoothness of surfaces defined by two polynomials

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces

Let $f(x,y,z)$ be a polynomial of three variables. Then

$f=0$ (which is a two dimentional object) is smooth if and only if the system $f_x=f_y=f_z=0$ has only zero solutions.

I'm not sure if the above statment is the definition of smoothness or a theorem.

My question is if we have two polynomials F and G of four variables. Then $F=0, G=0$ together also defines a two dimentional object. How to tell if this surface is smooth or not?

Comment: It's not an if and only if, even if you add the condition $f = 0$ to the system (which you should).  For example, take $f(x,y,z) = x^3$.  $f = f_x = f_y = f_z = 0$ at $(0,y,z)$, but $x^3 = 0$ is smooth.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I found this definition: A smooth hypersurface is the set of points defined by $F=0$ with the property that the gradient of $F$ is nonzero at each point of the set.

Comment: @RobertIsrael According to this definition, x=0 is NOT a smooth hypersurface.

Comment: How is $x=0$ not a smooth hypersurface?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I also thought this is weird. But according to the definition from a textbook, $x=0$ is not smooth.

Comment: Why do you say it's not smooth?  The gradient of $x$ is $(1,0,0)$, which is nonzero.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That's interesting. But $x=0$ is the same surface as $x^3=0$. The latter has gradient $(3x^2,0,0)$, which is zero on the surface. How to explain this contradiction?

Comment: @RobertIsrael https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_an_algebraic_variety   For a hypersurface, the singular points are those at which all the partial derivatives simultaneously vanish. So $x^3=0$ is a singular hypersurface. "Non-singular" may not mean the same thing as "smooth": they just appear in different subjects.

Comment: Different functions  can generate the same surface.  "Smooth" should be an intrinsic property of the surface, not of the function you happen to be using to describe it.

Answer (score 0):

${\bf F}: (x_1,\ldots,x_4) \to (F(x_1, \ldots, x_4), G(x_1, \ldots,x_4))$ is a function from $\mathbb R^4$ to $\mathbb R^2$.  If ${\bf F}({\bf a}) = (0,0)$
and the Jacobian matrix $$ J = \pmatrix{ \partial F/\partial x_1 & \ldots \partial F/\partial x_4\cr \partial G/\partial x_1 & \ldots \partial G/\partial x_4\cr} $$ has rank $2$ at $\bf a$, then we can take two of the four variables such that the submatrix corresponding to their columns has rank $2$.  Let's say these are $x_1$ and $x_2$.  The Implicit Function Theorem then says there are
smooth functions $u_3(x_1, x_2)$ and $u_4(x_1,x_2)$ with $u_3(a_1, a_2) = a_3$ and $u_4(a_1, a_2)  = a_4$ such that in a neighbourhood of $\bf a$, the surface ${\bf F}({\bf x}) = 0$ is given parametrically by $(x_1, x_2, u_3(x_1, x_2), u_4(x_1, x_2))$ in a neighbourhood of $(x_1, x_2) = (0,0)$, and in particular is smooth.